# Imagemagick command through java not sending output to text file

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, imagemagick

I am using the imagemagick's compare command through java's ProcessBuilder.

I want to get the output of the comparison to a text file. My command is running fine however I am not getting any output in my text file. While running the same compare command through cmd I am getting the output as

```
C:\Image11.jpg JPEG 279x181 279x181+0+0 8-bit sRGB 15.8K
B 0.000u 0:00.000
C:\Image12.jpg JPEG 279x181 279x181+0+0 8-bit sRGB 15.8K
B 0.000u 0:00.000
Image: C:\Image11.jpg
Channel distortion: RMSE
red: 0 (0)
green: 0 (0)
blue: 0 (0)
all: 0 (0)
```

Any suggestions on what might be the problem. Here is my code..

```
public class Test {
  public static void colorROI(String[] command) throws IOException{

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = pb.start();
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("D:/log.txt");
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("global");
    logger.addHandler(fh);

    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);
    String line = null;

      while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
      logger.log(Level.INFO, line);     
      }

   }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] command = {"cmd.exe","/c","cd \"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\" && compare -verbose -metric rmse \"C:\\Image11.jpg\" \"C:\\Image12.jpg\"  \"C:\\Image13.jpg\"" };

    colorROI(command);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it finally. Actually in imagemagick the output from the command is directed to the ErrorStream instread of the InputStream. Changing it to errorstream solved the issue.

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
```